# Can a windows form window be targeted by python?

Tags: python

all.

I'm trying to make a python script that fills 2 fields and clicks a button in a Windows Form (written in C#). What are relevant libraries that i can use to achieve this?

Comment: python library tkinter used for GUI

Comment: Thank you, @Sheri. But isn't tkinter used for GUI programming? What im trying to achieve is controlling an already built GUI program (written in C#) with python. Just trying to automate part of my workflow.

Comment: check out pyautogui

Comment: Thank you, @James. That should do the trick!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per James comment, [PyAutoGUI](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is the way to go! Thank you James

Edit: Upon doing further research, there seems to be another library called [PyWinAuto](https://pywinauto.github.io/). Here is a [comparison](https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/8bymeo/pyautogui_vs_pywinauto/) between the two.